# How to change the path of /tmp folder in ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tmp

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 server. I have a couple of apps that are running and therefore can't reboot occasionally. Because of this my /tmp folder is filling up pretty fast and sometimes I have problem with logging in to the server

I want help with redirecting /tmp to another path like /mnt so I will be able to clear it periodically.

Comment: A few different things come to mind: making `\tmp` a symbolic link (probably a bad idea in case the link breaks for some reason), mounting another volume on `/tmp` or, probably best, configure your applications to store temporary data elsewhere.

Comment: Hi @Phil , If I do symlink, all the files will be stored in /mnt and not in /tmp?

Also, please let me know how to mount another volume in /tmp

I can't change anything in the applications configuration as I can't restart them

Comment: Yes, if you make `/tmp` a symlink to an existing folder everything will be stored there. The same is true for mounting another volume on `/tmp` with something like `mount /dev/sdX1 /tmp` where `/dev/sdX1` is the disk you want to mount – you will need to put in the device of the disk you are planning to use – see `man mount` for details. However, doing this while the the program in question is still running may not give the desired result if the application keeps writing to the same file and never releases the file handle. Also it may be confused  by older temp files vanishing...